# Proof of some Riemann problem

Tags: analysis, riemann-zeta, divergent-series

I was wondering if anyone is aware of this proof about the Riemann Hypothesis.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.4143.pdf

What I like about it is his analytic approach using the behaviour of general series at singular points. Since I haven't heard anything about it, I presume there must be some flaw somewhere, but I can not find it. To me it seems legit. In particular I want to point out his main result. I added short variations of the proofs which should be sufficient to capture the entire essence. The paper with that regard is somewhat cumbersome.

---

He resums the $\zeta$-function, compares it with its integral representation and obtains an expression valid for $\sigma>0$ ($s=\sigma+it$)

$$(s-1)\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{S_n(s)}{n+1} \tag{0}$$

where $S_n(s)=-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k \, k^{1-s}$.

Then he defines a function $\zeta(s,x)$ valid for $|x|<1$ by

$$(s-1)\zeta(s,x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{S_n(s)}{n+1} \, x^n$$

which converges to (0) for $\sigma>0$ as $x\rightarrow 1$. He uses a result for the asymptotic behaviour of $S_n(s)$ as $n$ gets large
$$\frac{S_n(s)}{n+1} \sim \frac{1}{n(n+1)(\log n)^{1-s} \Gamma(s)} \left( 1 + {\cal O}\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right) \right)\tag{as.1}$$

which probably inspired him to look for functions $\phi_s(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \phi_n(s) \, x^n$ whose coefficients $\phi_n(s)$ have the same asymptotic behaviour with respect to $n$. Such a function is
$$\phi_s(x)=(1-x)\left(\frac{\log(1-x)}{-x}\right)^{s}$$

whose coefficients obey 
$$\phi_n(s) \sim \frac{-s}{n^2 (\log n)^{1-s}} \left( 1 + {\cal O}\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right) \right)\tag{as.2}$$

as $n$ gets large.

---

Since $\phi_s'(x)$ diverges to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 1$ it follows that $\zeta'(s,x)$ diverges to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 1$. This allows him to establish the result (after a lot of details)
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{(s-1)\zeta'(s,x)}{\phi_s'(x)} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{nS_n(s)}{n+1}}{n\phi_n(s)} = \frac{-1}{\Gamma(s+1)} \, . \tag{1}$$

In a similar but different way as in the pre-print this can be easily seen as follows.

**proof:** Define $a_n\equiv\frac{nS_n(s)}{n+1}$ and $b_n\equiv n\phi_n(s)$, so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{-1}{\Gamma(s+1)} \equiv c$. This is equivalent to saying $\frac{a_n}{b_n}=c+\epsilon_n$ for some complex sequence $\epsilon_n$ that vanishes as $n\rightarrow \infty$. From the asymptotics (as.1) and (as.2) it is seen that for large $n$
$$|\epsilon_n| = {\cal O}\left(1/\log n\right) \, .$$
To establish the result, $a_n = cb_n + \epsilon_n b_n$ is used to construct
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n = c \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n x^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n b_n x^n$$
from which it then follows if we can show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\epsilon_n b_n|$ converges. But from the asymptotics for $|\epsilon_n|$ and $|b_n|$ this sum can be bounded
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty |\epsilon_n b_n| \leq C|s| \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log n)^{2-\sigma}}$$
for a suitable constant $C<\infty$. The convergence of the right sum follows by the integral test for $0<\sigma<1$.

---

From this it can be deduced: If $s$ is a non-trivial zero, then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{(s-1)\zeta(s,x)}{\phi_s(x)} = \frac{-1}{\Gamma(s+1)} \, . \tag{2}$$

**proof:** Define $\delta(x)\equiv \frac{(s-1)\zeta'(s,x)}{\phi_s'(x)} + \frac{1}{\Gamma(s+1)}$, so that the previous result is compactly written as $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \delta(x) = 0$. Let $s$ be a non-trivial zero and integrate (the previous proof showed that $\zeta'(s,x)$ has the same singularity at $x=1$ as $\phi_s'(x)$ which is manifestly integrable in a neighbourhood $\leq 1$)
$$\int_x^1 \delta(t) \phi_s'(t) \, {\rm d}t = -(s-1)\zeta(s,x) - \frac{\phi_s(x)}{\Gamma(s+1)}$$
or
$$-\frac{\int_x^1 \delta(t) \phi_s'(t) \, {\rm d}t}{\phi_s(x)} = \frac{(s-1)\zeta(s,x)}{\phi_s(x)} + \frac{1}{\Gamma(s+1)} \, .$$
It suffices to show that the LHS vanishes absolutely as $x\rightarrow 1$, for this
$$\left|\frac{\int_x^1 \delta(t) \phi_s'(t) \, {\rm d}t}{\phi_s(x)}\right| \leq \frac{\int_x^1 |\delta(t)| \, |\phi_s'(t)| \, {\rm d}t}{|\phi_s(x)|} \, .$$
The nominator ($f(x)$) and denominator ($g(x)$) on the RHS are differentiable on the open interval $(x,1)$ and finite at $x<1$, so Rolle's theorem (for the function $h(t)=f(t) - \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \, g(t)$) or equivalently L'Hospital can be applied. The RHS becomes in the limit $x\rightarrow 1$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} |\delta(x)| \, \frac{|\phi_s'(x)|}{-|\phi_s(x)|'} = 0 \cdot 1 = 0 \, .$$

---

In the final step he considers the ratio of (2) for the zero $s$ and $1-s$

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \left|\frac{(s-1)\zeta(s,x)}{\phi_s(x)}\frac{\phi_{1-s}(x)}{(-s)\zeta(1-s,x)}\right| = \left|\frac{\Gamma(2-s)}{\Gamma(s+1)}\right| \tag{3}$$

or

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \left|\frac{\phi_{1-s}(x)}{\phi_s(x)}\right| = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \left( \frac{\log(1-x)}{-x} \right)^{1-2\sigma} = \left|\frac{\zeta(1-s)\Gamma(1-s)}{\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)}\right| $$

which is an equation only possible when $\sigma =1/2$ in which case the LHS is 1, which is indeed true for any real $t$ on the RHS when using the functional equation for the $\zeta$-function

$$\left| \frac{\zeta(1-s)\Gamma(1-s)}{\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)} \right| = \left| \frac{(2\pi)^{1-s}}{2\sin(\pi s/2)\Gamma(s)} \right| = 1 $$

and $\left|\Gamma(1/2+it)\right|^2 = \frac{\pi}{\cosh(\pi t)}$.

---

**Wrong...** As most probably have expected, the proof is fundamentally flawed. I've been thinking about this for some time now and am somewhat embarassed to say that the solution is so trivial. It would have saved me lots of time, if somebody here would have pointed it out earlier, since it could have been seen from my given exposition, but here we go...

The problem with the proof lies within its formulation. It utterly overcomplicates matter where not necessary. This distracts from the relevant point and superficially makes it look as if it were correct, just like shenanigans try to distract their prey. While I have already simplified the steps significantly (I believe), it already more or less starts with Equation (1). It is not even wrong, but should have been more properly written as
$$(s-1)\zeta'(s,x) = -\frac{\phi_s'(x)}{\Gamma(s+1)} + {\cal O}(1)$$
for $x\rightarrow 1$, in order to keep track of error-terms. This shows that both functions share the same logarithmic singularity at $x=1$.

Now when integrating this Equation from $x$ to $1$, it is not yet assumed that $s$ is a zero. This gives rise to the identity $$(s-1)\zeta(s,x)=(s-1)\zeta(s) - \frac{\phi_s(x)}{\Gamma(s+1)} + {\cal O}(1-x)$$
as $x\rightarrow 1$, which is just the expansion of $(s-1)\zeta(s,x)$ about the singular point $x=1$.

Now if $s=s_0$ is a zero with $0<\Re(s_0)<1$, then the constant term of the expansion vanishes identically, so that Equation (3) becomes
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \left|\frac{(s_0-1)\zeta(s_0,x)}{(-s_0)\zeta(1-s_0,x)}\right| = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \left| \frac{\phi_{s_0}(x)}{\phi_{1-s_0}(x)} \frac{\Gamma(2-s_0)}{\Gamma(s_0+1)}\right| \\ \stackrel{!}{=} \lim_{s\rightarrow s_0} \left| \frac{(s-1)\zeta(s,1)}{(-s)\zeta(1-s,1)} \right| = \lim_{s\rightarrow s_0} \left| \frac{(s-1)\zeta(s)}{(-s)\zeta(1-s)} \right| \, .$$

This is where the flaw becomes apparent, because the interchange of limits is generally wrong and would have to be crucially justified. Evidently it would be the main part of the proof!

I should also mention, that Equation (0) - even though he might have found it independently - can actually be traced back to a version from H. Hasse (1930).

Comment: It seems strange to write a paper that consists of two completely separate parts and says in the middle that the second part has nothing to do with a lot of things in the first part, and to claim to prove the Riemann hypothesis in the second part, without announcing this in the abstract. One might expect that if you wanted to prove the Riemann hypothesis, the paper would be focused on that. It may just be slightly eccentric, but it's the sort of thing that makes one think that it may well be just the next crank... Anyway, I haven't found anything obviously wrong so far...

Comment: Yes I give you that. That is kind of weird. I belive he just wanted to share his thoughts in the first part without releasing an extra paper about it, since he didn't deem it worth of a separate paper. If there is a flaw in the second part, it is probably some big subtlety.

Comment: It all sounds reasonable on the surface. The proof would be surprisingly elementary if it were correct. I'm not sure whether I'll take the time, but one should be able to check the second part without huge efforts. How did you come across this?

Comment: I just typed ``on the zeros of the riemann zeta function`` into google.

Comment: 3.9 has a small error: aside from an unfortunate mixing of $n$'s, the denominator should certainly have $n^{n+1}$, not $(n+1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Yeah maybe (didn't check), that belongs to Part 1 which I didn't read so much. It is more so Part 2 what I'm talking about.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31441.

Comment: #1, I haven't read the paper. #2, despite #1, I'm sure there's no proof of RH there. #3, despite #2, I don't see any reason for closing the question. On Mathoverflow, there is a long-established policy of not vetting papers, and this question would, accordingly, be closed. On math.stackexchange, I don't think there is any such policy, and the question makes a welcome change from the two thousand variations on "how do you differentiate $x^2$?" There is real mathematics in this question (even though the paper may well be worthless) and I'd like to see someone take a crack at it.

Comment: @Diger: I think rewording was a better idea than deleting. There's no question in the post now. It seemed to turn out in the meta thread that you mistook this Q&A site for a discussion board. I think you should take a decision on whether you want to continue to seek a genuine discussion on this, and take it elsewhere, or whether you're interested in asking a question about this paper in the sense in which the community on this site sees itself as answering questions. I think there are legitimate questions to be asked about the paper. The post very likely won't be reopened without a question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: If you don't like to read the draft, I suggest to read the versions I added above. I believe they are short enough for everyone to at least have a look at.

Comment: @amWhy: This seems like a reasonable closure but do you think in light of GM's comment an exception might be made?

Comment: Finally I found the error... I added the solution. I apologize to GM! You were right, but you still could have shown me the flaw ;)

Comment: @daniel: What I meant is his statement about "I'm sure there's no proof of RH there". He was right I suppose...

Comment: Still I'm somewhat disappointed why nobody pointed it out... It was seeable from the exposition.

Comment: What I find interesting. I contacted the author and told him about the flaw, but he doesn't want to see it. He basically said $x=1$ being a singular point changes everything...Whatever the case I'm confused whether the above concern is legitimate or he just wants to troll other people.